# Factoring algebraic polynomials that are neither cyclic nor symmetric, and don't have obvious zeros

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

In a set of $40$ problems, I was not able to factor these three polynomials. (The polynomials are neither cyclic nor symmetric, and don't have obvious zeros.) Any help is appreciated:

1) $x^3+2 \sqrt{3} x^2-2 \sqrt2.$

2) $x^3+x^2(1+y)-x(20+y)+20y.$

3) $x^3+(5-a)x^2+(8-3a)x-2a+4.$

Answer (score 1):

The first two are irreducible over the fields generated by their coefficients.
The third does factor.  Hint: for a linear factor $x+c$, $c$ must divide the constant term.

Comment: That seems like a great answer, but could elaborate on how  you know the first two are irreducible?

Comment: I used Maple... but if doing it by hand you could try the appropriate version of Gauss's lemma.